# How to integrate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}\:dx,
\end{equation}
which has arisen from a problem I'm working on? I've noticed I can do the following:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sqrt{-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}\:dx & =\int_0^1\sqrt{\left(-x^4\right)\left(x^2-1\right)-\left(x^2-1\right)}\:dx \\[3ex]
& = \int_0^1\sqrt{\left(-x^4-1\right)\left(x^2-1\right)}\:dx \\[3ex]
& = i\int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(x^4+1\right)\left(x+1\right)\left(x-1\right)}\:dx
\end{align}
But where do I go from here? Also, I'm a bit unsure about my last step above, i.e. not sure if it would be the right route to take.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try a numerical method, i see no other way

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Clearly you are mistaken.

Comment: I'd simplify things and get rid of the $i$ by using $(1 + x^4)(1+x)(1-x)$

Comment: You shouldn't take that $i$ out of the square root. In that interval the polynomial is positive.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 should I never take out an $i$ where the polynomial is positive? I apologize, I haven't yet attacked any harder integral problems of this type.

Comment: hi Sarah, please tell me why i'm mistaken, i have said i see no other way, probably see you an other way? It is not clear for me

Comment: @bd1251252 Why would you? The whole purpose of doing it is to change the sign of the thing you're taking the square root of.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I see, thanks!

Comment: $P(x)=\dfrac{1-x^8}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^1\sqrt{-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\sqrt{x^4(1-x^2)+1-x^2}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\sqrt{(1-x^2)(x^4+1)}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{(1-\sin^2x)(\sin^4x+1)}~d(\sin x)$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\cos^2x)\sqrt{\sin^4x+1}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\sin^2x)\sqrt{\sin^4x+1}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{4n}x}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!\sin^{4n+2}x}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(4n)!\pi}{2^{6n+1}(n!)^2(2n)!(1-2n)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(4n+2)!\pi}{2^{6n+3}(n!)^2(2n+1)!(1-4n^2)}$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals#Recurrence_relation.2C_evaluating_the_Wallis.27_integrals)

Answer (score 0):

I think I can simplify it some, but I can't run it to ground.

Let $\theta = \cos^{-1} x$, so $x = \cos \theta$ and $dx = -\sin \theta \:d\theta$.  Also $1 - x^2 = 1 - \cos^2 \theta = \sin^2 \theta$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}\:dx & =
\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^0 -\sin \theta\sqrt{-\cos^6 \theta + \cos^4 \theta - \cos^2 \theta + 1} \:d\theta\\
& = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \sin \theta\sqrt{(\cos^4 \theta + 1)(1 - \cos^2 \theta)} \:d\theta\\
& = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \sin^2 \theta\sqrt{\cos^4 \theta + 1} \:d\theta\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I've also derived what you have. What if we also let $x=\sin\left(\theta\right)$, and added the solutions together to get something that looks like $$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(\theta\right)\sqrt{\cos^4\left(\theta\right)+1}\:d\theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(\theta\right)\sqrt{\cos^4\left(\theta\right)+1}+\cos\left(\theta\right)\sqrt{\sin^4\left(\theta\right)+1}\:d\theta. $$ Is there any way we might evaluate this resulting integral, and then divide the end result by $2$?

Comment: And the sines and cosines should be squared of course, I simply forgot to sub for $dx$....